# Marquee stops on mouseover

Tags: html

I have a problem when I move mouse cursor on moving text it is being stopped.

I want to stop moving the text on mouse over..

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" onmouseover="this.stop();">

Pervaiz

</marquee>
```

Comment: marquee is non-standard and will not be supported going forward. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/w6fdB/

Answer (score 2):

Really I would recommend you to not to use the `marquee` in this age. We have a lot of option to achieve it using simple css or js or jquery. So go for them but anyway the solution of your above problem would be this

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseleave="this.start();">
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hh57K/1/)

Comment: Thanks Sachin for advise.